# How to retrieve the directory structure of the zend framework 2 in hierarchy

Tags: zend-framework2

I plan to develop a module for Zend Framework 2 which will produce some files under the folders of controllers and models directory. I want to give an option to the end user that under which module or directory he would like to place the file.

How can I retrieve the directory structure and name of modules in a Zend Framework 2 project?

Comment: Is this type of meta project modification scheme compatible with good security and stability for your app? Would it make more sense to create a separate app to modify the directory structure and contens of this app?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins my app is more like a plugin and it allows to make zf2 forms through gui, I want is to work in a way that it will ask the end user in which module he wants to make a form and the app will automatically place the form there, plus I don't think it will be convenient for the end user to change his directory structure